# Can't apply CredSSP Oracle Remediation patch to Hyper-V 2012R2

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2

So I recently installed Hyper-V Server 2012R2 in a home lab and loaded some VMs on it.

I threw Win10 on a laptop to connect with Hyper-V Manager to access those VMs.  The 10 box then rebooted and applied all patches, which is fine.  It broke the ability to connect to my hypervisor however.

On the hyper-v I checked for updates - none found.  I manually downloaded KBs 4103715 and 4103725, as well as 4103726 just in case.  All claimed not to be applicable to this operating system.  I'd prefer to patch my hypervisor rather than force a vulnerability through, but I cannot find a way to do so.  Suggestions?